# Context-sensitive grammar for function calls

Tags: context-sensitive

Say we have context-free grammar for function declarations and calls (C-style)

```
START = DECLLIST CALLLIST
DECLLIST = FDECL DECLLIST | FDECL
CALLLIST = FCALL CALLLIST | FCALL

FDECL ::= fname lbrac TARGS rbrac semicolon
TARGS ::= TARGFST TARGSREM
TARGFST ::= type name
TARGSREM ::= comma type name | comma type name TARGSREM

FCALL ::= fname lbrac ARGS rbrac semicolon
ARGS ::= ARGFST ARGSREM
ARGFST ::= name
ARGSREM ::= comma name | comma name ARGSREM
```

Non-terminal in uppercase.

Example is:

```
foo(int x, int y);
bar(int x);
foo(x, y);
bar(x, y); // shall be recognized an error but not in CFG
```

Now I want to amend this with context-sensitive rule: any function call need the same number of arguments as its declaration. I understand this will cost me some context-sensitive productions with two or more non-terminals on the left.

This will yield a context-sensitive grammar for decls and calls.

I need some ideas how to build this grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can determine by looking for examples with Google, the answer seems to be: it can be done, but please don't.

Regarding context-sensitive rules, Chomsky wrote: *Rules of this kind are quite common in actual grammatical description* (on p. 363 of: [Handbook Of Mathematical Psychology Volume II, Chapter 6](https://archive.org/details/handbookofmathem017893mbp/page/362/mode/2up)). What sort of rule did he have in mind? Have context-sensitive grammars actually been applied to the description of languages? I haven't been able to locate any examples.

To see how it can be done, look at how to generate the language $\{ a^nb^nc^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, e.g. [in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar), and adapt the same technique to your use case.

The approach to generating $\{ a^nb^nc^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is some variation of this:

- Use context-free rules to generate the right amounts of elements without trying to get the order right:

  $ S \rightarrow \epsilon \\ S \rightarrow aSBC $
- Use noncontracting rules to shift elements into position to get the order right:

  $CB \rightarrow BC$
- Replace the shifted elements with terminals:

  $aB \rightarrow ab \\ bB \rightarrow bb \\ bC \rightarrow bc \\ cC \rightarrow cc$

We now have a noncontracting grammar, so

- Use the standard technique for replacing noncontracting rules with context-sensitive rules:

  $CB \rightarrow BC$ becomes

  $CB \rightarrow CZ \\ CZ \rightarrow WZ \\ WZ \rightarrow WC \\ WC \rightarrow BC$

Done.

The same approach can be applied to your use case: generate the function definitions and applications together, then shift the applications into place.

The problem is that this is quite convoluted.  We really want to just match up the signatures of function definitions and their applications; we don't want to generate things out of order and then have rules to gradually shift them into place. It's unnatural and quite hard to read.

The next problem is that with context-sensitive or noncontracting grammars, we can't do any better.  The only way to guarantee equality of numbers of $a$s, $b$s and $c$s is to make sure they are generated "at the same time", which can only be done by generating them out of order, which means the shifting is inevitable. (Clearly, this is not a formal proof.)

So the next problem is: if context-sensitive grammars do not provide a natural way of expressing this sort of constraint, what sort of grammar can we use instead?

Well, let's go back to where Chomsky got his idea of context-free grammars: grammars of natural languages, as they have been used in teaching languages for at least the past 2500 years.  In such grammars, nonterminals have grammatical features. For instance, in European languages such as English and Russian, noun phrases and verb phrases have the features *number* (singular, plural, etc.) and *gender* (masculine, feminine, etc.), and possibly more.  We can then express [agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agreement_(linguistics)) w.r.t. these features, e.g. subject-verb agreement w.r.t. number.  Or, in your case, agreement of function signature between function definitions and their applications.

So we need [attribute grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute_grammar)s, in which we can attach such features to nonterminals, and express such agreement.

Attribute grammars allow a direct, natural way to express these constraints. We can not only require the number of arguments of function calls to match up with the number in their definitions, we can also require their types to match up. We can even specify arbitrary type checking if we want to.

One approach to attribute grammars is [Van Wijngaarden grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Wijngaarden_grammar), which not only allow attributes to be specified for nonterminals, but also completely formalize the manipulation of attribute values.  A Van Wijngaarden grammar for $\{ a^nb^nc^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$:

```
S: A(n) B(n) C(n).

A():.
B():.
C():.

A(1n): a A(n).
B(1n): b B(n).
C(1n): c C(n).

n:: .
n:: 1 n.
```

The rules with `:` are the ordinary grammar rules. The attribute `n` has been added to the nonterminals to express the number of terminals to be generated.

The rules with `::` are the meta-rules. They specify the possible values of the attributes; in this case, of `n`.

In this notation, whitespace is insignificant. (Notation for Van Wijngaarden grammar varies.)

`1n` is the string `1` concatenated with the value of the attribute `n`. `n` is an attribute because it is a nonterminal in the meta-grammar.

The magic is in the requirement that within the same rule, different mentions of the same attribute must have the same value. As a consequence, in the first rule, the three different mentions of `n` must have the same value.

As promised, using the `n` attribute allows us to equate the numbers of $a$s, $b$s and $c$s directly, without having to do the symbol shifting required in noncontracting grammars.

In Van Wijngaarden grammars, all attribute values are strings and there are no predefined operations on them, except concatenation. As a result, for complex tasks, quite a large portion of the resulting grammar is dedicated to manipulating complex attribute values using pattern matching, which can look convoluted in its own way.

A Van Wijngaarden grammar for your use case:

```
START:
  DECLLIST(dl) CALLLIST(cl) match(dl with cl).

DECLLIST(dl1+dl2):
  FDECL(dl1) DECLLIST(dl2).
DECLLIST(dl):
  FDECL(dl).

CALLLIST(cl1+cl2):
  FCALL(cl1) CALLLIST(cl2).
CALLLIST(cl): FCALL(cl).

FDECL(name->targs):
  fname(name) lbrac TARGS(targs) rbrac semicolon.

TARGS(name->type,rem):
  TARGFST(name->type) TARGSREM(rem).

TARGFST(name->type):
  type(type) name(name).

TARGSREM(name->type):
  comma type(type) name(name).
TARGSREM(name->type,rem):
  comma type(type) name(name) TARGSREM(rem).

FCALL(name->args):
  fname(name) lbrac ARGS(args) rbrac semicolon.

ARGS(name->type,rem):
  ARGFST(name->type) ARGSREM(rem).

ARGFST(name->type):
  name(name->type).

ARGSREM(name->type,rem):
  comma name(name->type).
ARGSREM(name->type,rem):
  comma name(name->type) ARGSREM(rem).

match(name->targs with name->args):
  match_args(targs,args).

match(name->targs with name->args,rem2):
  match(rem1 with rem2)
  match_args(targs,args).
match(name->targs,rem1 with name->args,rem2):
  match(rem1 with rem2)
  match_args(targs,args).

match(name1->targs1,name1->targs1,rem1 with rem2):
  match(name1->targs1,rem1 with rem2).
match(rem1 with name1->args1,name1->args1,rem2):
  match(rem1 with name1->type1,rem2).

match(name1->targs1,name2->targs2,rem1 with name2->args1,name1->args2,rem2):
  match(name1->type1,name2->type2,rem1 with name1->type1,name2->type2,rem2).

match_args(name1->type with name2):.

match_args(name1->type,rem1 with name2,rem2):
  match_args(rem1 with rem2).

dl1:: dl.
dl2:: dl.
dl:: name->targs.
dl:: name->targs,dl.
targs::.
targs:: name->type,targs.
name:: letter.
name:: letter letterordigit.
letter:: a.
letter:: b.
[...]
letter:: z.
letterordigit: letter.
letterordigit: digit.
digit:: 0.
digit:: 1.
[...]
[...]
```

As you can see, the attributes accumulate all of the relevant information, essentially, data structures expressed in the form of parseable strings.  The characters I've inserted, such as `+` and `->` and `with`, have no special significance, they are just characters being concatenated into strings with the values of the attributes. At the top level, in the first rule, we end up with the list `dl` of function declarations and the list `cl` of function calls. We can't just equate them; we have to allow for declarations without any calls (I suppose) and the lists may contain duplicates (I suppose) and may be in a completely different order.

That is what the `match` and `match_args` nonterminals take care of. They perform pattern matching, in the style of Prolog and functional programming languages such as Haskell.

Which leaves me with the final problem; why don't we all specify our grammars using Van Wijngaarden grammars, or some other form of attribute grammar, and instead, are still stuck with being taught the Chomsky hierarchy and limiting technology such as Yacc and ANTLR?  Why do we insist on hiding away attribute manipulation within the parser's implementation?

The answer to that is a combination of technical objections, politics, and ignorance.  But that is a story for another person and another time.

Comment: Thanks, was not aware about  Van Wijngaarden grammars,

Answer (score 1):

In a real compiler, normally we don't enforce this kind of rule in the grammar itself.  Instead, we parse to a parse tree using a grammar that doesn't enforce this rule; and then we follow it up with a programmatic check on the parse tree to check whether it follows this rule (e.g., whether it obeys the type system, etc.).

Comment: Sure I know how it is done in clang and GCC frontends. In fact I submitted some patches in both. I have pure academic interest in how to create CS grammar from CF + semantic rules.

Comment: When I studied Computer Science in Nijmegen, we wrote a compiler using grammars that do handle this (using CDL2), and frankly, I don't understand why this approach (attribute grammars or some variation) didn't become the standard approach in the field.